# Convert localized string into decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string, that could look like "123,34", "123123,09", "1234", "123.34", "123123.09"

(Stringrepresentation of 10,2 decimal that will be stored into a MySql DB)

Due to the culture of the ASP.net thread may differ, because my application supports localization, I need to find a safe way to convert the most likely user input into a decimal.

How is that possible?

I tried various Decimal.Parse attemps, that all failed so far.

**Solution**:
My final solution was a mixed one. I used string replace to ensure my date is formatted into the specified CultureInfo I used for parsing

Comment: Note to responders:  The question is not how to parse a decimal, it is how to parse a decimal when the culture is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal.Parse is the way to go but you need the particular overload that incorporates localisation, [Decimal.Parse Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326786%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You should read current Culture Info
and than you could

```
//CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 

Convert.ToDecimal(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the decimal is turned into a string, there is really no foolproof way of telling which culture formatting was used to format it.
You have two options :

1. Record the formatting culture used and pass that back with the string, then use that for the appropriate `decimal.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)`
2. Perform the parse at the UI level (where the culture is known) and pass the value back as a decimal type.

Comment: Excellent point. Microsoft actually recommends a similar practice with dates, as with storing the timezone separately from the actual date value.

Answer (score 1):

```
Decimal.Parse (String, IFormatProvider)
```

where IFormatProvider is culture-specific format for your strings

Answer (score -2):

Convert your string with the InvariantCulture

Decimal.parse(yourstring,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Thought you might get some weird results if your string is not compatible with the cultureinfo of the system.